# Lose connection with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, connection

I have a big problem with Firebase. the app logs off from Firebase, without saying anything, in fact by starting the app marks me that the user is logged properly. But this is not reality, because for example when I go to add an item in the Firebase database, it is saved locally but not on the server. This is a problem because the data does not are saved and I need a re-authenticate to re-establish the connection. And when I do unsaved data are eliminated.
that gives me the error is as follows. I've already seen a question on stack but I have been of help. the file that requires the mistake I successfully downloaded. I can not understand why this thing happens to me, the first did not.
I thank you for the help

```
W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Provided authentication credentials are invalid. This usually indicates your FirebaseApp instance was not initialized correctly. Make sure your google-services.json file has the correct firebase_url and api_key. You can re-download google-services.json from https://console.firebase.google.com/.
```

EDIT
the problem is when i restart device. when i turn on the device the notification receiver load automatically an alarm for notification, i think that it is that do the problem of firebase. how do I resolve this?

notification receiver

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

Calendar calendar;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("SETTING_NOTIFICATION", MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("on", true))
        Notification(context);


}

private void Notification(Context context){
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent1);
}
```

}

in manifest

```
 <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name=".NotificationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the google-services.json file as mentioned in the error log. Can you download it again from your firebase project and try again? Or maybe post the source code of the function where you are facing the issue.

Comment: I have already tried to download that file again, but he did the same thing. 
The problem takes in the whole app, An example is the code I have just entered. Every now and then loses the connection until they redo log

Comment: It is as if it would manage only the items locally, without loading it on Firebase server

Comment: can u try making a simple sample app with just login and a data access to see if the problem is in your code or something else?

Comment: Initially the app was very simple and everything worked properly. It worked well with this code. The last thing I implemented, and perhaps caused by that but it seems strange is the addListenerForSingleValueEvent () method. It could be caused by this?

Comment: Try changing it to addValueEventListener()

Comment: I changed it. This error occurs to me when I do so many app updates, it does not happen right away. These may also be multiple updates of the app to cause these problems? In any case we see if the change works in the future

Comment: In my experience, firebase data retrieval has been a little slow so that might be the same for you. Did changing the function make it work?

Comment: OK thanks! in the coming hours I will test this modification, and I know you say more! thanks for now! there is a way to know if the connection is really lost?

Comment: even with that change, the problem is not resolved. 
After various tests we think the loss of connection problem occurs when I turn off the device. I use local notifications and when you turn on the DEVICE is automatically activated an alarm for notifications, perhaps this is interference?